# How can i create a low pass filter in matlab

Tags: filtering

i am trying to create a low pass filter in matlab for a project in signals and systems class but i couldn't. cut off frequency is 500 , sampling frequency is 10000 and the low pass filter's band width is  150 Hz. If you help me i would be very appreciated

Comment: like this: h = fir1( N ,  500*2/10000).   Where N is the order of the FIR filter typically choose 20 to 50 for a moderate transition width. Note that a **lowpass** filter with cutoff frequency of 500 hz cannot have a bandwidth of 150 Hz.

Answer (score 0):

filterDesigner Filter Designer
    filterDesigner launches the Filter Designer.
    Filter Designer is a Graphical User Interface (GUI) that allows you to
    design or import, and analyze digital FIR and IIR filters.

```
If the DSP System Toolbox is installed, Filter Designer seamlessly
integrates advanced filter design methods and the ability to
quantize filters.

% Example:
%   Launch Filter Designer.

filterDesigner;     % Lanches Filter Designer
```

See also fvtool, signalAnalyzer.

```
Reference page for signal/filterDesigner
```